# SQLServer Calculate Average of Multiple Columns

Tags: sql-server, average

I have generated a table using PIVOT and the ouput of columns are dynamic. One of the output is as given below:

```
user       test1   test2    test3 
--------------------------------
A1          10      20       30  
A2          90      87       75
A3          78      12       34
```

The output of above table represents a list of users attending tests. The tests will be added dynamically, so the columns are dynamic in nature.

Now, I want to find out average marks of each user as well as average marks of each test.

I am able to calculate the average of each test, but got puzzled to find out the average of each user.

Is there a way to do this??

Please help.

Mahesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do it on your data source before you pivot it?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the marks for each user then divide by the number of columns:

```
SELECT
    user, 
    (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3 AS average_mark
FROM users
```

Or to ignore NULL values:

```
SELECT
    user,
    (ISNULL(test1, 0) + ISNULL(test2, 0) + ISNULL(test3, 0)) / (
         CASE WHEN test1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
         CASE WHEN test2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
         CASE WHEN test3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    ) AS average_mark
FROM users
```

Your table structure has two disadvantages:

- Because your table structure is created dynamically you would also have to construct this query dynamically.
- Because some students will not have taken all tests yo may have some NULL values.

You may want to consider changing your table structure to fix both of these problems. I would suggest that you use the following structure for your table:

```
user   test    mark
-------------------
A1     1       10
A2     1       90
A3     1       78
A1     2       20
A2     2       87
A3     2       12
A1     3       30
A2     3       75
A3     3       34
```

Then you can do this to get the average mark per user:

```
SELECT user, AVG(mark) AS average_mark
FROM users
GROUP BY user
```

And this to get the average mark per test:

```
SELECT test, AVG(mark) AS average_mark
FROM users
GROUP BY test
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My data contains NULL values as well, so taking the average by number of columns may give wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to [UNPIVOT](http://www.tsqltutorials.com/unpivot.php) the same way you just PIVOTed. But the best answer is to not do the PIVOT in the first place! Store the unpivoted data in a table first, then from *that* do your PIVOT and your average.